# Angular 6 Transform to Object

Tags: angular, angular6

I have this function in Angular 6:

```
  getClients (): Observable<Client[]> {
    return this.http.get<Client[]>(this.clientsUrl, 
      { headers: httpOptions.headers, 
        observe: 'body', 
        responseType: 'json' 
      })
      .pipe(
        tap(clients => { 
          this.log(clients + ` fetched clients`)
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError('getClients', []))
      );
  }
```

But I'm recieving from the API this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "legal_name": "Company Name, Inc.",
    "trade_name": "Company",
    "created_at": "2018-05-27T23:16:53.669Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-27T23:16:53.669Z"
}
```

My model is in Pascal Case

```
export class Client {

public tradeName: string;
public legalName: string; 

constructor(legalName: string, tradeName: string) {
    this.legalName = legalName;
    this.tradeName = tradeName;
}}
```

How can I map `legal_name` to `legalName` and `trade_name` to `tradeName` to maintain consistency in the code?

Comment: By using the `map` operator and constructing your class instance from the JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your Obserbable

```
 getClients (): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.clientsUrl, 
      { headers: httpOptions.headers, 
        observe: 'body', 
        responseType: 'json' 
      }).map(res =>{
           return { 
              legalName: res.legal_name,
              tradeName: res.trade_name,
              //... 
           }
      });

  }
```

If your Client interface has correctly the name fields then replace `any[]` with `Client[]`